# Getting MultiValueDictKeyError while checking if a field is empty

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a regsitration form where a user chooses a plan. I am trying to check that if the field is empty a message should be displayed. The field name is **plan**. The code is below

```
if password1==password2:
            if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'User with same email already exists')
                return redirect('register')
            
            elif plan is None:
                messages.info(request, 'Please select a plan')
                return redirect('register') 
            else:
                user=CustomUser.objects.create_user(full_name=full_name.upper(),age=age, phone_no=phone_no, address=address, plan=plan, email=email.lower(), password=password1)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                
                usr_otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
                UserOtp.objects.create(user = user, otp = usr_otp)
                mess =  f"Hello, {user.full_name},\n Please enter the otp to validate your email and activate your account. \nYour OTP is {usr_otp} .\n Thanks!"
                
                return render(request, 'register.html', {'otp': True, 'user': user})
                # return redirect('login')
```

I have tried multiple ways to check whether the plan field is empty or not such as

elif plan == ' '

elif not plan

elif plan is None

elif request.POST['plan'] == ' '

for all these I am getting only one error

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /account/register
'plan'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'plan'
Exception Location: C:\Users\rickb\Envs\virenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py, line 78, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\rickb\Envs\virenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\rickb\\Envs\\virenv\\jgs',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\Envs\\virenv',
 'C:\\Users\\rickb\\Envs\\virenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 06 Dec 2021 23:30:33 +0530
```

I don't understand why I am getting this, Please correct me what I am doing wrong and how to check that the **plan** field is empty.

The **plan** field in the html is a radio button that passes a value

Comment: Did you try printing plan? Maybe there is something wrong with the plan variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

`elif request.POST.get('plan') == ' '`

In python square brackets give error if there is no entry whereas *get* function returns None..

Comment: Oh so sorry, I did not notice that the answers are from two different people.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the reason also why should i use .get()

Comment: Because get function returns ```None``` if ```plan``` won't exist while ```[]``` returns ```MultiDictError```

Comment: okay, thank you I am clear about the concept now

Answer (score 1):

If the plan field is empty, the key `'plan'` won't exist in `request.POST`. So to verify if this field is empty you can do this

```
elif request.POST.get('plan') is None:
```

Since `get` will return `None` if the plan field is empty.

Comment: Thank you, for explaining the difference, I shall user POST.get() from now on to use take inputs.